# tornado-redis, Client has no attribute geoadd

Tags: tornado, tornado-redis

I am using tornado-redis with tornado websockets to access redis in an asynchronous manner. When I try a `set`

```
value = yield Task(self.client.set, 'value', 100)
```

this returns `True` and runs perfectly, but when I replace this line with a `geoadd` command like this

```
value = yield Task(self.client.geoadd, 'value', lat, lng, 'v1')
```

this results in an error:

```
AttributeError: 'Client' object has no attribute 'geoadd'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, the problem was the version of the package. The most updated version available on `pip` is `2.4` whereas the recent version on git is `2.5`. I used cloned it from git and everything was working fine.